# Scanning multidimensional string with space in c

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, input, space

I'm trying to make a simple voucher. So, I used a multidimensional string. But facing trouble including space in those strings. Instead, I took words as input. But is there any way to include space? My code is given below-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int sum =0, n, i;
    puts("Please input how many transactions you want to enlist: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char list[301][51];
    int amount[301];
    puts("Please enter the name of your transaction and the amount: (Press space or enter to toggle between name and amount . And avoid using spaces in the name; use underscore instead.)");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){

        scanf("%s %d", &list[i], &amount[i]);
        sum += amount[i];
    }
    list[0][n+1] = '\0';
    amount[n+1] = '\0';
    puts("");
    printf("\t\t\t\t Voucher\n\n");
    puts("  Ser.|\t Name \t\t\t\t\t\t\t|Amount");
    puts("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++ ){
        printf("  %03d |\t %-50s\t|%6d\n", i+1, list[i], amount[i]);
    }
    puts("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("      |  Total\t\t\t\t\t\t\t|%6d", sum);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you could use the `%[` [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) specifier, to read all characters until you hit a digit, and write it into `list[i]`.

This will leave you with a trailing space in `list[i]`, but that can be trimmed if you don't want it.

The `scanf` call could then look something like

```
scanf(" %50[^0-9]%d", list[i], &amount[i]);
```

Note the leading space in the format string, to tell `scanf` to skip white-space (like the newline from the previous line), and the width-specifier to not read more than can fit in `line[i]`.

Of course, that prevents you from having numbers inside the string you read. To solve this problem you need to go a more complicated route.

For example by reading the whole line into a buffer, and then find the last space in the string. You can then copy the contents before the last space to `list[i]`, and convert the contents after to an `int` value for `amount[i]`.

Comment: But %[] specifier is not working in this problem i dunno why